# passing variable through header

Tags: php, mysql, database, search, header

I am making a recipe website and in order to process the search query i am processing on a separate page called "search.php"
The form:

```
<form id="recipehome" form method="post" action="search.php">
 <p>I want a 
         <Select name="dropoption">
             <option value="empty">----</option>     
            <?php echo $cuisinetype;?>    
            </Select>

            <Select name='meal'>
                    <option value="B">Breakfast</option>
                    <option value="l">Lunch</option>
                    <option value="D">Dinner</option>
            </Select>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="Feed Me" value="submit" /> 
       </form>
```

My Search page:

```
if(trim($_POST['submit']) =="submit"){
        }else{              
            if (isset($_POST['dropoption']) && ($_POST['dropoption'] != '')){
                if (isset($_POST['meal']) && ($_POST['meal'] != '')) {

                $dropoption = clean_string($db_server, $_POST['dropoption']);
                $meal = clean_string($db_server, $_POST['meal']);
                $quer = "SELECT recipeid FROM `recipename` WHERE `cuisine_type` ='$dropoption' AND `b_l_d` ='$meal'LIMIT 0,1";
                mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database);
                $querya= mysqli_query($db_server, $quer); 
                if (!$querya) die("database access failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server));
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($querya)){
                            $searchresult .=$row['recipeid'];
                            }
                $searchresult = clean_string($db_server, $searchresult);            
                header("Location:results.php?recipeid=$searchresult");//
                }//if(meal)//
            }//if(cuisine)//    
        } //if(trim)//
    }
```

The query is then executed there and then I am trying to redirect from there to another results page by passing the variable i got as a result i have managed to get this into the url but i am having problems now plugging this integer into my database as a query. This page is called results.php

```
if (!$db_server){
    die("unable to Connect to MYSQL: " . mysqli_connect_error($db_server));
    $db_status = "not connected";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `recipename` WHERE `recipeid`='$searchresult'";
            mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database);
            $result=mysqli_query($db_server, $query); 
            if (!$result) die("database access failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server));
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                        $recipename .="<h1>". "Why dont you have ".$row['mealname']."</h1>";
                        $ingredients .="<p>".$row['ingredients']."</p>";
                        $recipe .="<p>" .$row['recipe']."</p>";
                        $cookingtime .="<h4>" .$row['hours']." Hours".$row['minutes']." Minutes </h4>";
                        $mealpic .="<img src='http://ml11maj.icsnewmedia.net/Workshops/Week%207/".$row['imagepath']."'/>"; 

                        if(trim($_POST['Submit']) =="submit3"){
                            if ($comment != ''){
                                $userid = trim($_SESSION['userid']);
                                $comment = trim($_POST['comment']);
                                $userid = clean_string($db_server, $_SESSION['userid']);    
                                $comment = clean_string($db_server, $_POST['comment']);

                                        $query = "INSERT INTO Comments (comment,userid,recipeid) VALUES ('$comment','$userid','$receipeid')";
                                        mysqli_query($db_server, $query) or
                                        die("Insert failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server));
                                        $message = "Thanks for your comment!";  
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Try using parameter binding instead, your code is subject to mysql injections. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: This setup seems flawed, you should reengineer your code. Why split the processing (of the same action in essence) over two different files and send state variables along explicitly through the query-string? But as pointed out below it appears you need to retrieve and sanitize _recipeid_ from the request.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the variable.
On the results.php page, try using this before the query:

```
$searchresult = $_GET['recipeid'];
```

Comment: would i do this on the search.php page?

Comment: No, this goes on the results.php page.

Comment: You are missing the closing bracket here: if (!$db_server){
    die("unable to Connect to MYSQL: " . mysqli_connect_error($db_server));
    $db_status = "not connected"; }